# Unwanted outdent in the first paragraph of a section

Tags: indentation, xepersian

for the first paragraph of some of my sections I have an unwanted outdent as the following picture:

---

[image]

I used `noindent` after the `section`, but has no effect. There is also no extra hidden character there. I use `xepersian` package and `xelatex` for typesetting. It only occurs for some sections and not all of them!

This is the minimum code:

```
%
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=5.1cm, bottom=4.6cm, left=3.8cm, right=3.8cm}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Yagut}
%\setstretch{1.54}
\linespread{1.54}
\SepMark{-}
\begin{document}


\chapter{مسئله یادگیری}

این یک آزمایش است. 

\section{چارچوب مسئله یادگیری }
\noindent
نقطه اشتراک مسائلی مانند پیش‌بینی‌های اقتصادی، تشخیص علت بیماری، بینایی ماشین و موتورهای جستجو چیست؟ همه این مسائل از یادگیری از داده بهره می‌برند. فهرست چنین کاربردهایی بسیار طولانی است. اجازه دهید بحث را با یک مثال از زندگی واقعی شروع کنیم و نشان دهیم که یادگیری از داده به چه شکل صورت می‌گیرد. 

مسئله امتیازدهی به یک فیلم را در نظر بگیرید. اگر شما صاحب یک شرکت اجاره فیلم باشید، این مسئله برایتان مهم است. زیرا قصد دارید بدانید هر مشتری احتمالاً به چه نوع فیلمی علاقه‌مند است و فیلم مناسب را به وی پیشنهاد دهید. 

\noindent 


\end{document}
```

**Update:** if I just add a single word like "به" to the first line of the paragraph the problem is resolved!! also if I remove the `geometry` part the problem is fixed.. it seems it relates to typesetting and spacing...

Comment: hard to debug from just an image, try to make a small but complete single paragraph document that shows the problem, just start from a copy of your document and delete everything not needed... with code it should be easy to trace what is causing the offset

Comment: Without some code to test, this question is likely to never get answered. Almost nobody here knows persian. With code, it doesn't matter which language is shown/used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to add a minimum code

Comment: do you get an "overfull hbox" warning about this line?  it might be a situation where the "overfullness" is still acting left-to-right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I do, `Overfull \hbox (10.98302pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 18--20
[]\EU1/XBYagut(0)/m/n/10.95 نقطه اشتراک مسائلی مانند پیش‌بینی‌های اقتصادی، تشخیص علت بیماری، بینایی ماشین و موتورهای[]`

Comment: which engine do you use? since you mention `xepersian` i'll guess xetex.  although i think xetex is likely to be the miscreant here, i think `xepersian` should be looked at too.  your statement that adding a single short word to the problem line is the key to identifying what's happening.  another way to work around the problem might be to apply `sloppypar` to the paragraph, or allowing some `\emergencystretch`.  but if overfull lines are pushed out to the right in a totally right-to-left environment, that ought to be fixed, or at least reconsidered.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you! is `sloppypar` restricted to just the following paragraph? because I don't want it affects all the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apparently even in RTL text, xetex makes overfull boxes stick out to the right (probably as it uses tex--xet mechanism to invert each horizontal box separately)

Not being able to read the script I can't suggest a way to help line breaking other than use `\sloppy` which allows white space to stretch more or just setting `\emergencystretch` which is less drastic than `\sloppy` but also enough in this case. `\fussy` puts the settings back to normal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=5.1cm, bottom=4.6cm, left=3.8cm, right=3.8cm}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Yagut.ttf}
%\setstretch{1.54}
\linespread{1.54}
\SepMark{-}
\begin{document}


\section{چارچوب مسئله یادگیری }
نقطه اشتراک مسائلی مانند پیش‌بینی‌های اقتصادی، تشخیص علت بیماری، بینایی ماشین و موتورهای جستجو چیست؟ همه این مسائل از یادگیری از داده بهره می‌برند. فهرست چنین کاربردهایی بسیار طولانی است. اجازه دهید بحث را با یک مثال از زندگی واقعی شروع کنیم و نشان دهیم که یادگیری از داده به چه شکل صورت می‌گیرد. 

\section{چارچوب مسئله یادگیری }
\sloppy
نقطه اشتراک مسائلی مانند پیش‌بینی‌های اقتصادی، تشخیص علت بیماری، بینایی ماشین و موتورهای جستجو چیست؟ همه این مسائل از یادگیری از داده بهره می‌برند. فهرست چنین کاربردهایی بسیار طولانی است. اجازه دهید بحث را با یک مثال از زندگی واقعی شروع کنیم و نشان دهیم که یادگیری از داده به چه شکل صورت می‌گیرد. 

\section{چارچوب مسئله یادگیری }
\emergencystretch=2em
نقطه اشتراک مسائلی مانند پیش‌بینی‌های اقتصادی، تشخیص علت بیماری، بینایی ماشین و موتورهای جستجو چیست؟ همه این مسائل از یادگیری از داده بهره می‌برند. فهرست چنین کاربردهایی بسیار طولانی است. اجازه دهید بحث را با یک مثال از زندگی واقعی شروع کنیم و نشان دهیم که یادگیری از داده به چه شکل صورت می‌گیرد. 

\fussy
مسئله امتیازدهی به یک فیلم را در نظر بگیرید. اگر شما صاحب یک شرکت اجاره فیلم باشید، این مسئله برایتان مهم است. زیرا قصد دارید بدانید هر مشتری احتمالاً به چه نوع فیلمی علاقه‌مند است و فیلم مناسب را به وی پیشنهاد دهید. 




\end{document}
```

TeX does warn you about this

```
Overfull \hbox (10.98302pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14
```

so you should be able to ignore it until final edits done, then just check the log file  and fix any bad paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

`sloppypar` is an environment. so it you wrap

```
\begin{sloppypar}
...
\end{sloppypar}
```

around just one paragraph, that's the only paragraph that will be affected.

this is an alternative to rewriting, and should be used sparingly.

those are the only two "limited" alternatives that i know of.