# Word wrapping in XeLateX RTL Urdu occurring right not left

Tags: xetex, right-to-left

Why does the following Urdu text seem to be word wrapped on the right and not left? If a word cannot be adjusted , shouldn't it be jutting out into the left margin, not the right? Am I missing some option of the bidi package?

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% texlive 2017
  \TeXXeTstate=1
  \documentclass[17pt]{memoir} 

\setstocksize{5.25in}{4in}
\settrimmedsize{5.25in}{4in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{4.3in}{3in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{-4pt}{10pt}
\setheaderspaces{20pt}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text}
    \setmainfont[Renderer=Graphite]{Scheherazade}
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2 %

    \usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}
اُردُو (یا جدید معیاری اردو) ہندوستانی زبان کی معیاری قسم ہے۔ یہ پاکستان کی قومی اور رابطہ عامہ کی زبان ہے، جبکہ بھارت کی چھے ریاستوں کی دفتری زبان کا درجہ رکھتی ہے۔ بھارتی آئین کے مطابق اسے 22 دفتری شناخت زبانوں میں شامل کیا جاچکا ہے۔ 2001ء کی مردم شماری کے مطابق اردو کو بطور مادری زبان بھارت میں 5.01\% فیصد لوگ بولتے ہیں اور اس لحاظ سے یہ بھارت کی چھٹی بڑی زبان ہے جبکہ پاکستان میں اسے بطور مادری زبان 7.59\% \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is unavoidable with how RTL text works in `xelatex`. I gather it always lays boxes out LTR. I would have thought this was a duplicate question, but I can't find a suitable question to link to. I did find [this post](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2016-November/026912.html) on the xetex mailing list.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311770/87678

Comment: That's answers my question. As I didn't find these links, does it make sense to mark this as a duplicate and point to the links?

Comment: I think the question is slightly different to the other one I linked to and deserves an answer of its own. I'll cite David's comments on the `xetex` mailing list and make a new answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2016-November/026912.html) on the `xetex` mailing list, this is a symptom of how the XeT--TeX model (which e-TeX uses with `\TeXXeTstate=1`) of RTL typesetting works.

David Carlisle writes:

> That really is just a symptom of the basic problem with the tex-(-)xet
>   model, the paragraph builder is essentially *always* building a LTR
>   paragraph, you can only use `\beginR/endR` *within* the paragraph to
>   typeset text runs in the opposite direction. There is no way to say
>   "build a right to left paragraph" corresponding to `\pardir`.

So the options to fix things are to set a `\sloppy` paragraph (or increase `\emergencystretch`) as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311842/87678) or use `lualatex` which uses `\pardir` to set RTL paragraphs.